# Increase speed of functions, which are working with listView items

Tags: listview, c++-cli

### *Background*

I am working on an application which use `listView`, and I have write some functions for make actions with items in `lisyView`. I have actions as `OnClickCopyAllDomains` and `OnClickMarkAllDomains`. This functions works with domains (listView items) and when `listView` contain more then 100.000 item I feel how working speed goes down. So below I will show you functions, and I want you to give me advance ***how I can improve speed of functions?***

***OnClickMarkAllDomains***

This function set `listView` items checked state to ***true***.

```
System::Void MainForm::OnClickMarkAllDomains(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        for( int i=0; i<listViewDomainsInfo->Items->Count; ++i )
            listViewDomainsInfo->Items[i]->Checked = true;
    }
```

***OnClickCopyAllDomains***

In this function I copy `listView` items (domains) to the clipboard, I if domains count is more then 100.000 I wait for 5 minutes till action ends.

```
System::Void MainForm::OnClickCopyAllDomains(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        int itemsCount                  = listViewDomainsInfo->Items->Count;
        System::String^ outputClipboard = System::String::Empty;

        for( int i=0; i<itemsCount; ++i ) {
            outputClipboard += listViewDomainsInfo->Items[i]->Text + "\r\n";
        }

        if( !System::String::IsNullOrEmpty( outputClipboard ) ) {
            try {
                System::Windows::Forms::Clipboard::SetText( outputClipboard );
            }
            catch( ... ) { }
        }
    }
```

### Question

***How I can make my functions better, increase their speed ?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call [`listViewDomainsInfo->BeginUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.beginupdate.aspx) before your loops and [`listViewDomainsInfo->EndUpdate()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.endupdate.aspx) after.

Also, string concatenation as you're using it is extremely inefficient. Make `outputClipboard` a [System::Text::StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) rather than a System::String.

Comment: And what about copping to clipboard ?